# Python deque: difference from list?

Tags: python

I'm reading the Python Documentation: I don't understand how a deque is different from a list. From the documentation:

> Returns a new deque object initialized left-to-right (using append())
>   with data from iterable. If iterable is not specified, the new deque
>   is empty.
>
> Deques are a generalization of stacks and queues (the name is
>   pronounced “deck” and is short for “double-ended queue”). Deques
>   support thread-safe, memory efficient appends and pops from either
>   side of the deque with approximately the same O(1) performance in
>   either direction.
>
> Though list objects support similar operations, they are optimized for
>   fast fixed-length operations and incur O(n) memory movement costs for
>   pop(0) and insert(0, v) operations which change both the size and
>   position of the underlying data representation.

If a deque is basically a list, but more efficient, why would one use a list in place of a deque?

Comment: You can't slice deques, for example

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A deque is more efficient *for pushing and popping from the ends*.  Read on, and below the list of methods you'll find:

> Indexed access is O(1) at both ends but slows to O(n) in the middle. For fast random access, use lists instead.

Adding to or removing from the beginning of a list is O(n), but fetching elements from the middle is O(1).  For a deque, the reverse is true.

So generally you only want a deque when you don't care about what's in the middle; you want to feed it things in some order and then get them back in that order elsewhere.

Comment: For some applications, the rotate method on a deque is also elegant and useful, even if you don't care about efficiency

Answer (score 10):

`Deque` is a doubly linked list while `List` is just an array.

Randomly accessing an object at index i is O(n) for `Deque` but O(1) for `List`.

Fast insertions and deletions at the beginning is the biggest advantage of `Deque`.
Fast random reads is the advantage of `List`.

If insertions and deletions happen randomly in the middle of the container, `Deque` will have to find the node (O(n), then insert a new node (O(1)), while `List` having to move some nodes (O(n)).

They both have their use cases.

Answer (score 2):

A list is supposed to be iterated and/or randomly accessed.
Typical usage: store a collection of homogeneous data items.

A queue is designed to be operated at the end/beginning.
Typical usage: store data with priority information, facilitating a wide/depth-first search.

Answer (score 1):

This will be really helpful in addition to the answers given above. From the documentation:

> It is also possible to use a list as a queue, where the first element
>   added is the first element retrieved (“first-in, first-out”); however,
>   lists are not efficient for this purpose. While appends and pops from
>   the end of list are fast, doing inserts or pops from the beginning of
>   a list is slow (**because all of the other elements have to be shifted
>   by one**)

For more details about time complexity analysis: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity